# How to install pytorch in windows?

Tags: pytorch

I was wondering, if there is any way to install pytorch in windows like the way we can install tensorflow. My machine is not supporting docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyTorch should work fine in WSL (CPU only).

Comment: installed pytorch using wsl and conda

Answer (score 6):

As of August 14, 2017, you can install Pytorch from `peterjc123`'s fork as follows. Currently, python 3.5 and 3.6 are supported.

```
# If your main Python version is not 3.5 or 3.6
conda create -n test python=3.6 numpy pyyaml mkl

# for CPU only packages
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch

# for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, CUDA 8
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80

# for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, CUDA 9
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda90

# for Windows 7/8/8.1 and Windows Server 2008/2012, CUDA 8
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch_legacy cuda80
```

pytorch support for windows [Link](https://github.com/peterjc123/pytorch-scripts)

Comment: the link is broken.

Comment: @jdhao: updated the link

Comment: As of this time, tensorflow-gpu, for Windows, doesn't support CUDA 9. However, I've installed both CUDA 8 and CUDA 9 side-by-side. tensorflow-gpu works with CUDA 8 and pytorch works with CUDA 9.